# Scoped UID for Activerecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have this structure:

```
Enterprise
  has_many :projects

Projects
  has_many :clients

Clients
  has_many :tasks
```

I'm trying to give each Enterprise a start from 1 to their tasks.
So, I did:

```
Tasks
  to_param
    uid.to_s
  end
```

And in my controllers to find a Task:

```
Task.find_by_uid(params[:id])
```

All urls are pretty, scoping the task number per enterprise. (I handle the uid at the task creation, incrementing the last uid from the same enterprise)

However, the Task.find_by_uid doesn't scope only tasks from the current_user.enterprise.

It seems to be a very noob question, by I'm struggling to find out a solution.

Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rails 2.3.8 doen't accept nested associations, you must accomplish that with some scope in another models.

Found the solution [here](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/has-many-through-habtm.html)

Thanks.